# Scrapy: command to overwrite previous export file

Tags: python, scrapy, export, overwrite

**Set-up**

I export my data to a .csv file by the standard command in Terminal (Mac OS), e.g.

```
scrapy crawl spider -o spider_ouput.csv
```

---

**Problem**

When exporting a new `spider_output.csv` Scrapy appends it to the existing `spider_output.csv`.

I can think of two solutions,

1. Command Scrapy to overwrite instead of append
2. Command Terminal to remove the existing `spider_output.csv` prior to crawling

I've read that (to my surprise) Scrapy currently [isn't able](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/547) to do 1. Some people have proposed [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140457/scrapy-overwrite-json-files-instead-of-appending-the-file), but I can't seem to get [it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33487592/7326714) to work.

I've found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40328141/7326714) to solution 2, but can't get it to work either.

Can somebody help me? Perhaps there is a third solution I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an open issue with scrapy for this feature:
https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/547

There are some solutions proposed in the issue thread:

```
scrapy runspider spider.py -t json --nolog -o - > out.json
```

Or just delete output before running scrapy spider:

```
rm data.jl; scrapy crawl myspider -o data.jl
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I've tried your deleting line, and it works! :)

Comment: @LucSpan great, if it answered your question don't forget to click "accept answer" button to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use big O:

```
scrapy crawl spider -O spider_ouput.csv
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

option `-t` defines the file format like json, csv, ...

option `-o FILE`  dump scraped items into FILE (use `-` for stdout)

`>filename` pipes output to filename

**altogether we get for overwriting previous export file:**

replace output file instead of appending:

> scrapy crawl spider -t csv -o - >spider.csv

or for json format:

> scrapy crawl spider -t json -o - >spider.json